# do not apply css style to child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

we have

```
<div class="xTable">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div class="xTable">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="xTable">
         <table>...</table>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>    
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

How do I apply custom css styles to **2nd div**, only to 2nd div and not to 1 or 3 or deeper?

NO WAY TO ADD EXTRA CLASSES or IDS! Html is generated dynamically and is unmanageable.

I would use

```
.xTable table .xTable
```

but that means 3rd and deeper divs will be affected.

no IDs! Please CSS selectors only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To cater fully for both this default markup and browsers which *correctly* add a `tbody` where it isn't already specified you'd need to use:

```
body > .xTable > table > tr > td > .xTable,
body > .xTable > table > tbody > tr > td > .xTable {
    ...
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/H6dpe/).

This assumes that your first `<div class="xTable">` has no parents other than `<body>`. If this isn't the case then replace `body` with your parent.

Comment: so in a case of complex hierarchy I need to specify EACH child? I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: The `>` selector selects the [child](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) element and nothing deeper. `body > .xTable > .xTable` wouldn't work as `.xTable` isn't a direct child of `.xTable`; equally, `body > .xTable > table .xTable` would apply the styling to all `.xTable` elements contained within the first `.xTable`'s child `table` (thus styling both your 2nd and 3rd `.xTable` elements). In order to select no deeper elements you'd have to work like this. `x parent of y parent of z ...` rather than `x parent of y parent or grandparent of z ...`.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just give the 2nd div an extra css class.

`<div class="xTable second-xTable-div"></div>`

Comment: Agreed. This is the most correct solution from a semantic markup point of view.

Comment: html is generated dynamically, that's not the case. I need pure css.

Comment: @gr9zev Can't you generate the css class with it? Or is it that generic that it is completely unmanagable?

Comment: I cannot, it's being generated from complex 3d party.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `:not` selector to exclude the parent and then having a long list of child combinators might do the job:

```
:not(table) > .xTable > table > tr > td > .xTable
```

You might need to mix in the implicit tbody elements to that though.

A nicer solution would probably be:

```
.xTable .xTable {
    foo: bar;
}

.xTable .xTable .xTable {
    foo: Whatever it would have been if the previous selector didn't match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Then could this not be just:

```
body > .xTable table tr td.xTable {STYLES}
```

????

Comment: No `.xTable` is a *child* of another. They descendants at a rather deeper level than that.

Comment: all .xTable's have already their styles. Only the 2nd needs to be overridden, deeper level elements must not be affected.

Comment: Be sure to replace body with whatever your container element is.

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying that you can't add class name as provided by @Rob, then I think there is only one way to go with javascript or jquery. Below I provided solution using jQuery.

```
$('.xTable:eq(1)').css('backgroundColor','green'); //Selects the second .xTable class div
```

Check more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `someelement someotherelement` it is not important how much deep you go in the first element. But you can add a `>` between them to select only the `someotherelement` that is exactly the child of `someelement` like this: `someelement > someotherelement` and it will not select childs of childs of the first selector.

Answer (score 0):

Class composition is recommended. for example `<div class="table level-2" />`